# Nested sequence of non-empty compact subsets - intersection differs from empty set

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, compactness

I have the following proposition:

"If $(S_n)$ is a sequence of compact subsets of a metric space such that

$S_1 \supseteq S_2 \supseteq ... \supseteq S_n$

Then $\bigcap^\infty_{i=1} S_i$ $\neq$ $\emptyset$"

My lecture notes provide the following proof, whose last step I don't understand:

---

Proof: Assume by way of contradiction that $\bigcap^\infty_{i=1} S_i$ = $\emptyset$. Let $V_n := (S_n)^c$ for each $n$. The class $\mathbb{C} :=\{V_n: n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ is an open covering of $S_1$. Since $S_1$ is compact, $\exists I$ finite, $I \subset \mathbb{N}$, s.t $\{V_i: i \in I \}$ covers $S_1$. Let $n:=max(I)$. The class $\{V_1, ..., V_n \}$ also covers $S_1$ and we get the following contradiction

$\emptyset = \bigcap^n_{i=1} S_i = S_n$

---

So, I don't get the part from "Let $n:=max(I)$..." onwards, especially the contradiction. I have tried applying DeMorgan's Law and the only way the last equalities makes sense is if the union of $\{V_1, ..., V_n \}$ equals the whole metric space, a property I haven't been able to understand from the steps of the proof. This is a corollary to the finite intersection property, so it must have a connection but again I can't quite get it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If $\bigcap S_i = \emptyset$, then $\bigcup V_i =$ the entire space.

Comment: Yes, but does that mean that the union of $\{V_1, ..., V_n \}$ equals the whole space? Because it covers $S_1$, but $S_1$ isn't the whole space.

Comment: Your problem is solved if you understand that the complement is taken with respect to $S_1$ (and not with respect to whole space) ie $V_n=S_1\setminus S_n$. This needs to be mentioned explicitly.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh But in that case, I need to consider $S_1$ as being my whole metric space, so that the complement of $S_1$ is the empty set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $x \in S_1$. As we assumed at the start that $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty S_n  =\emptyset$, $x$ cannot be a member of all $S_n$ so some $n_0$ exists such that $x \notin S_{n_0}$, or equivalently $x \in V_{n_0}$. So the $V_n$ cover $S_1$.

Note that as the $S_n$ are decreasing, so the $V_n$ are increasing, so when we have a finite subcover, the one with the largest index (which exists by finiteness) is a superset of all of them, so we have a subcover consisting of one set, say $V_k$. But this cannot be, as any point of $S_k$ (which exists, as these sets are non-empty) is by definition not covered by $V_k$. This contradiction shows that the original assumption of $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty S_n = \emptyset$ was false.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It makes totally sense. So the contradiction is that, if $V_k$ covers $S_1$, and since $S_1 \supseteq S_k$, then $V_k$ would contain $S_k$. 

In the proof I presented in the question, when it's written "$S_k = \emptyset$, it is because the only way $V_k$ could contain it's complementary is if it was the empty set; so the contradiction is the same, just through another lens, right?

Comment: @jpugliese you’re welcome. The contradiction is basically the same yes. Also note that we can remove $V_1$ because it contributes nothing to covering $S_1$ anyway.

Comment: question, so in the end did we contradict the fact that $S_n$ are all nonempty? Because then $S_k$ ends up being empty, a contradiction.

Comment: @HossienSahebjame the intersection being empty ( the first assumption) leads to $S_k$ being empty for some $k$ which is already a contradiction to the assumptions. So the first assumption was false.

Comment: oh that's right cause we began with assuming the intersection was empty, got it!