# Let $f:[a,b] \rightarrow [a,b]$ be a continuous function. Define $p_0 = p \in [a,b]$ and $p_{n+1} = f(p_n)$ prove that

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functions, continuity

Let $f:[a,b] \rightarrow [a,b]$ be a continuous function. Define $p_0 = p \in [a,b]$ and $p_{n+1} = f(p_n)$ and let the set $K_p := \{p_n, n\geq 0\}$ be a closed set. Prove that $K_p$ is finite.

My attempt:

Either all elements of $K_p$ are isolated which would mean we could build a monotone sequence $a_n$ with all elements of $K_p$.

$a_n$ is clearly bounded as it lies in $[a,b]$ so it must converge to a limit $L$.

Because $K_p$ is closed $L \in K_p$ but a monotone sequence can only converge to a member of itself if $a_n = L, \forall n \geq n_0$ which would mean $K_p$ is finite.

Or $K_p$ has at least one acumulation point $x_0$. So we can take a sequence of $K_p$ converging to $x_0$ this would mean $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n = x_0$ but because $f$ is continuous $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(a_n) = f(x_0) \iff \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_{"n+1"} = f(x_0) = x_0$.
So all acumulation points of $K_p$ are fixed points but I can't finish the proof (that this would mean $K_p$ is finite). Actually this last paragraph got a little messy.

Comment: These are nice ideas  :)  One thing to note is that the set of fixed points of such an $f$ does not have to be finite (take $f(x)=x$, for example, or $f(x) = x + (x-a)\sin(1/(x-a))$). So we can't immediately finish off the problem in this way.

Comment: $x_0 \in K_p$ means $x_0 = p_m$ for some $m$ and if $x_0$ is a fixed point, $p_{m+1}=f(p_m)= p_m$ and $K_p$ has at most $m$ elements as the tail from $p_m$ onwards is constant.. $K_p$ being infinite means **no** $p_n$ can be a fixed point.

Comment: I just kinda need to fix the proof that $x_0$ is a fixed point, as $f(a_n)$ is probably not $a_{n+1}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $L_n=f^n(K_p)$, since $f$ is continuous, $L_n$ is compact, remark that $L_{n+1}\subset L_n$, we have $\cap_nL_n$ is not empty it contains $x\in K_p$ implies that $x=f^N(p)$. $x$ is an element of $L_{N+1}$ implies that $x=f^N(p)=f^{N+m}(p)$ implies that $K_p$ is finite.

Comment: why is the intersection not empty?

Comment: Because $L_n$ is compact

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2647708/nested-sequence-of-non-empty-compact-subsets-intersection-differs-from-empty-s

Comment: +1. I had a long complicated A prepared, but overlooked the fact that $\{p_n:n\ge j\}$ (which is $L_j$) is always closed.